# Unable to install EGit plugin on Eclipe Helios

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am unable to install Eclipse plugin for Git (EGit) in my Eclipse (**Helios version 2**).

Have tried to install EGit through url in eclipse install new Software : http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

I am getting below error :

**Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse EGit 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse EGit 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found**

I have tried but failed to install dependency mentioned above. So wondering if Git is supported on Helios.
Am i missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I am running Helios Service Release 2. I have tried installing eGit from the Helios site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios), but I get a similar error to the one described in this question. The Helios site references eGit version 0.11.1. The error mentions:

requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.0.20110607-2117]' but it could not be found

I assumed this would be related to the m2e plugin which appears to be the correct version: Eclipse.org - m2e version 1.0.0.20110607-2117. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade my Eclipse. Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

EGit 2.2 requires Eclipse 3.7 or greater, see ["What versions of Eclipse does EGit target?" in the FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F).

If you don't want to upgrade to Eclipse 3.7 or greater yet, you can still install EGit 2.1 from the following update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1

Comment: Seems more accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: thanks for the EGit target url link...i installed Indigo version and then was able to install EGit. Thanks.

Comment: @Fran: Please post a new question for that and be sure to include the full error message you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

When I use Helios I hava the same problem,Because of the version can't mathch, You can try installing it through the 1.0 version:

`http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-1.0`

It works!

PS:Indigo can work with `http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-1.3`

Engory yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Try installing it through the Helios update site:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
```

It should reference all plugins including EGit.

That being said, [robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456300/6309) (upvoted) points out to a dependency to Indigo (3.7), which could mean Helios (3.6) isn't supported.

Answer (score -2):

It worked for me.
OS: Ubuntu
Eclipse heliose

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-1.0

Comment: This is not an answer of what has been asked.